# the vite build output only contains index.html

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a legacy project created by react-create-app, now I want to switch the build tool from webpack to vite, this is my vite config look like:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    plugins: [react()],
    build:{
        outDir: "build"
    }
})
```

when I run the build command like this:

```
> pnpm run build

> snap-web@0.1.0 build /Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web
> tsc && vite build

vite v4.3.5 building for production...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
Generated an empty chunk: "index".
build/index.html  1.70 kB │ gzip: 0.94 kB
✓ built in 37ms
```

the output only contains a html file. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the entry point of your application in `index.html`:

```html
<body>
...
<script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
...
</body>
```